# Play beep with given frequency and length in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I'm looking for a method in iOS / Swift to play a tone with a specific frequency and length. The problem is, I cannot create media files which should be played, because the frequency and length depends on various factors. A solution for Xamarin would also work. I hope, anybody can help me.

Comment: Import the relevant module from the AudioKit library and use an Oscillator. You get to choose the frequency, length, envelope, everything.

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/building-a-synthesizer-in-swift-866cd15b731